# Problem reading from 3 tables in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

What do I do, I need to fetch data from 3 tables in mysql, here is my current query. All of the tables contain the IDNO which has 03A45 number. But this query isnt returning any results:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM father, mother, parents 
 WHERE father.IDNO=mother.IDNO=parents.IDNO 
   AND mother.IDNO='03A45' 
   AND father.IDNO='03A45' 
   AND parents.IDNO='03A45'
```

What would be the correct query for this?
All of the tables have the IDNO as primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select *
from
father 
inner join mother on father.IDNO = mother.IDNO
inner join parents on mother.IDNO = parents.IDNO
where
father.IDNO = '03a45'
```

Comment: How do I relate it with vb.net? I used this code, based on your code, but it doesnt work, it said that mother table is not unique alias:
  Dim sqlcom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from  mother, father, parents INNER JOIN mother on father.IDNO = mother.IDNO, INNER JOIN parents on mother.IDNO = parents.IDNO WHERE father.IDNO='" & TextBox14.Text & "'", sqlcon)

Comment: You are including tables twice - don't do **select * from mother, father, parents INNER JOIN...**, just **select * from mother INNER JOIN...**

Comment: @user225269: You're mixing ANSI-89 join syntax (in your question), while kristian's answer is ANSI-92.  You can't use both, and I recommend the ANSI-92 format.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT p.*,
       f.*,
       m.* 
  FROM PARENTS p
  JOIN FATHER f ON f.idno = p.idno
  JOIN MOTHER m ON m.idno = p.idno
 WHERE p.idno = '03A45'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code you've entered don't work because you entered a wrong sql command:

```
Dim sqlcom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from mother, father, parents INNER JOIN mother on father.IDNO = mother.IDNO, INNER JOIN parents on mother.IDNO = parents.IDNO WHERE father.IDNO='" & TextBox14.Text & "'", sqlcon)
```

The good query is the query give by Kristian

The principle on Inner Join is to join 2 tables:

The syntax is :

```
Select a.myFields, b.myFields
FROM myFirstTable as a INNER JOIN mySecondTable ON a.PrimaryKey = b.ForeignKey
INNER JOIN myThirdTable as c ON a.PrimaryKey = c.ForeighKey 'For 3Tables
```

It's just an example and you can use many others table.

Keep an eye on Sql courses. It's very powerful when you understand how it's working

Julien